# Show record counts in sidebar in laravel 8

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, sidebar, laravel-8

I am writing a project in Laravel 8. I want to show the number of each menu in the left menu. Actually I have a solution. Adding other models to all controls on the site. But this is not the right way. Is there an alternative to this?

For example:

```
My sidebar menus:
Tools (12)
Users (10)
Settings
```

I need to insert this code to all controls functions

```
$tools_1= Tools1::all()->count();
$users = Users::all()->count();
```

I am also write this code to the sidebar.

```
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="{{route('admin.x')}}" class="nav-link">
              <i class="nav-icon fas fa-warehouse"></i>
              <p>
                Tools
                <span class="badge badge-info right">{{ $tools_1 }}</span>
              </p>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="{{route('admin.y')}}" class="nav-link">
              <i class="nav-icon fa fa-car"></i>
              <p>
                Users
                <span class="badge badge-info right">{{ $users }}</span>
              </p>
            </a>
          </li>
```

Is there a more logical solution?

Comment: Sidenote, don't do `::all()->count()`; this is loading every record from your database table into memory, then counting the array elements. A simple `::count()` will perform a SQL count, and is faster and has less of an impact on performance. That being said, for 10 or 12 records, this is insignificant, but for larger tables, this would make a huge difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can move the sidebar markup to a partial - say sidebar.blade.php

Then use a view composer to pass data to the sidebar. Register the View composer in the boot method of a service provider - even AppServiceProvider is okay.

Use caching in the view composer for performance boost and limiting database queries

```php
//In the boot method of service provider
View::composer('sidebar', function ($view) {
    $counts = Cache::remember('counts', 3600, function() {
        return [ 'tools_1' => Tools1::count(), 'users' => User::count() ];
    });

    return $view->with('counts', $counts);
});

//OR you can use a wildcard to share data with multiple views
View::composer('admin.*', function ($view) {
    $counts = Cache::remember('counts', 3600, function() {
        return [ 'tools_1' => Tools1::count(), 'users' => User::count() ];
    });

    return $view->with('counts', $counts);
});
```

Laravel docs:

- https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#view-composers
- https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/cache#retrieve-store

Then in the partial you can use the data passed via view composer

```
<span class="badge badge-info right">{{ $counts['users'] }}</span>
<span class="badge badge-info right">{{ $counts['tools_1'] }}</span>
```

Comment: I write admin instead of sidebar and it worked. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You could extract sidebar to blade component and perform your query there.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#components